# Hyperledger Fabric Ecert's term

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, ca

I enrolled ECert by using fabric-ca-client.

I wonder when Ecert is expired?

Please tell me that.

Information

・I am using fabler sample. and not modify any parameter.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using all default configurations, an ecert will expire after 1 year from the time of enrollment. You can also use OpenSSL to inspect the certificate to see what is the expiration date it has. You can use the following command:

```
openssl x509 -noout -text -in <certFilePath>
```